# Handling huge file with tcl

Tags: scripting, tcl, stack-overflow

can anyone tell me how I can update the following procedure to handle big files please (size <= 10 G):

```
proc read_text_file { file } {
set fp [open ${file} r]
 set return_data ""

while { [gets $fp each_line] != -1 } {

lappend return_data ${each_line}

}
close $fp

return ${return_data}
}
```

my objective is to read a huge file line by line in a better runtime

Thanks

Comment: 50GB is a large file (bigger than physical memory on my machine right now). Do you really need it all in memory at once?

Comment: I had a file with that size any way need just to update the proc to get it able to handle huge files

Answer (score 2):

When you have a very large file, you categorically want to avoid bringing it all into memory at once. (Also, Tcl 8.* has a memory chunk allocation limit that makes bringing in 50GB of data *intensely* exciting. That's a long-standing API bug that's fixed in 9.0 — in alpha — but you'll have to put up with it for now.)

If you can, do a pass over the file to identify where the interesting sub-chunks of it are. For the sake of argument, let's assume that those are the lines that match a pattern; here's an example that finds where procedures are in a Tcl script (under some simple assumptions).

```
proc buildIndices {filename} {
    set f [open $filename]
    set indices {}
    try {
        while {![eof $f]} {
            set idx [tell $f]
            set line [gets $f]
            if {[regexp {^proc (\w+)} $line -> name]} {
                dict set indices $name $idx
            }
        }
        return $indices
    } finally {
        close $f
    }
}
```

Now you have the indices, you can then pull in a procedure from the file like this:

```
proc obtainProcedure {filename procName indices} {
    set f [open $filename]
    try {
        seek $f [dict get $indices $procName]
        set procedureDefinition ""
        while {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
            append procedureDefinition $line "\n"
            if {[info complete $procedureDefinition]} {
                # We're done; evaluate the script in the caller's context
                tailcall eval $procedureDefinition
            }
        }
    } finally {
        close $f
    }
}
```

You'd use that like this:

```
# Once (possibly even save this to its own file)
set indices [buildIndices somefile.tcl]
# Then, to use
obtainProcedure somefile.tcl foobar $indices
```

If you're doing this a lot, convert your code to use a database; they're a lot more efficient in the long run. The index building is equivalent to building the database and the other procedure is equivalent to doing a DB query.